# How to create database from "Model first" model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-model-first

I have been trying to follow the few tutorials on how to create a DB using the model first approach in MVC. I have gone as far as creating Entities in the designer and trying to generate a DB from the model. It creates SQL file fine but I cant seem to execute it? I have no option to do so? When I right click the file the execute option is not available and when I open the file and right click in the context the option is not available. I have tried connecting to a blank DB and then creating the Entity Model on this DB with model entities and then trying to generate a DB from the model but still no option to execute the sql from within VS2010 express. Is there a reason why its not there ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because VS2010 Express has limited features. 
I remember coming across some other "disabled" option in VS2010 Express during one of the Web Camps and the presenter at Microsoft told me that they do that to give you a taste, then you want to buy the professional edition.

I couldn't find a full list comparing all the features, but that's what it looks from this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express